# How can I open the savefile-dialog out of webview in an UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I've taken over an UWP project and have to fix an issue with a download button. On a website, there is a link to a software-package. The EXE can be downloaded using a browser. 
In my webview, as far as I understood, I won't be able to download directly to disk, but it should be possible to open the standard-browser to take over that part. I managed to open PDFs in the standard-browser from my webview. That already was tricky for me and my noob skills, but it's working now. I tried the same with EXE-files, but that doesn't seem to work. Here is what I did so far:

```
private async void WebView1_NewWindowRequested(WebView sender, WebViewNewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
            if (args.Uri != null && args.Uri.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains(".pdf"))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            { webView1.Navigate(args.Uri); }
        args.Handled = true;
    }
```

So this works for PDF, but when I do the same with EXE, it doesn't do anything (visible).

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I open the savefile-dialog out of webview in an UWP

You could listen [`NavigationStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting) event handler, if the uri contains `.exe` you could create [`BackgroundDownloader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader) to download exe file specific folder.

```
private async void TestWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Uri != null && args.Uri.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains(".exe"))
    {
        try
        {

            StorageFile destinationFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
                "test.exe", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(args.Uri, destinationFile);
            await download.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Mahobo solution**

```
 string Link = args.Uri.Segments.Last();
 try
 {
     var messagedialog = new MessageDialog("Saving File " + Link + " to your Download folder.");
     await messagedialog.ShowAsync();
     StorageFile destinationFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(Link, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
     BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
     DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(args.Uri, destinationFile);
     await download.StartAsync();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {


 }
```

Comment: Thanks Nico! Your answer brought me back on track. I modified it to

     string Link = args.Uri.Segments.Last();
                try
                {
                    var messagedialog = new MessageDialog("Saving File " + Link + " to your Download folder.");
                    await messagedialog.ShowAsync();
                    StorageFile destinationFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                        Link, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                    BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
...